# borland c++ builder how to make exe file with packages

Tags: c++builder, borland-c++

I don't know how create application to run on computer without Borland C++ Builder software installed.

Answer (score 10):

You need to go into the Project Options and disable the "Use dynamic RTL" setting in the Linker section, and disable the "Build with runtime packages" setting in the Packages section.